# Android frozen ProgressDialiog

Tags: android, progressdialog, loader

I want to add progress dialog when loading new activity. Its almost everything okay, excepts that ProgressDialog frozen.

My code:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public MyTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Do your loading here
        return "finish";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Intent editIntent = new Intent(
                "com.project.simplify.StartedReviewsEditActivity");
        editIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_OBJECT_ID, id);
        editIntent.putExtra("user", user);
        editIntent.putExtra("link", realLink);
        //review.putExtra("link", realLink);
        startActivity(editIntent);
        finish();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And I call this method on button click:

```
editButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyTask myTask = new MyTask(StartedReviewsActivity.this);
                myTask.execute("parameter");

            }
        });
```

Comment: With frozen what do you mean exactly?

Comment: If you are not doing anything in `doInBackground()` then why are you using `AsyncTask` ? Also your `Intent` declaration seems to be wrong.

Comment: Alberto - loading animation stops

Comment: My goal is to show loading dialog before starts new activity, so I found than need to use AsyncTask. Maybe know some other way to do this?
And what is wrong with Intent?

Answer (score 2):

move

```
 progressDialog.dismiss();
```

abovethis;

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(
                "com.project.simplify.StartedReviewsEditActivity");
        editIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_OBJECT_ID, id);
        editIntent.putExtra("user", user);
        editIntent.putExtra("link", realLink);
        //review.putExtra("link", realLink);
        startActivity(editIntent);
        finish();
```

so that it will be like this;

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
Intent editIntent = new Intent(
                "com.project.simplify.StartedReviewsEditActivity");
        editIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_OBJECT_ID, id);
        editIntent.putExtra("user", user);
        editIntent.putExtra("link", realLink);
        //review.putExtra("link", realLink);
        startActivity(editIntent);
        finish();
```

because you finish first your activity without dismissing first the progressdialog that causes the freeze.
Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Added, but it still freeze

Comment: If you want to show/freeze the animation of ProgressDialog, try to add something like Thread.sleep(2000); in your doInBackground method before return "finish";

Comment: It takes some time to load new activity, so I just want to show load animation before starts new activity.

Comment: try to add Thread.sleep(2000); before you call the progressDialog.dismiss();